# Installing ttf font with autoinst

Tags: fonts, pdftex, autoinst

I am trying to install the font [OpenSans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) into my TexLive 2021 installation in Ubuntu.

For that purpose I unpacked the OpenSans fonts and in the same directory I run the commands:

```
$sudo autoinst -verbose -sans -inferiors -fractions -sanserif -math *.ttf
$sudo texhash
$sudo updmap-sys
```

Later, I try to run the following program:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{OpenSans}

\title{OpenSans}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text \texttt{here} \textrm{roman} \textbf{bold} \textit{italic} \emph{emph} \textsf{SansSerif}
\end{document}
```

However, when I compile my program pdflatex, I obtain the following error:

```
(base) daalvarez@almarhall:~/Downloads/Open_Sans$ pdflatex test2.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/OpenSans/OpenSans.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file test2.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/OpenSans/T1OpenSans-OsF.fd) [1{/var/lib/texmf
/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test2.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 OpenSans-Regular-osf-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for OpenSans-Regular-osf-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps OpenSans-Regular-osf-t1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file OpenSans-Regular-osf-t1--base): Font OpenSans-Reg
ular-osf-t1--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Using XeLaTeX is not an option, since I need to compile a book produced with LaTeX in 2010, using packages that are incompatible with XeLaTeX (psfrag), using another set of fonts.

What to do?

Comment: you must enable the map file, something like `updmap-sys -enable Map=opensans.map`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer now the program compiles without issues, but the fonts are not replaced in the document. What should I do?

Comment: what do you mean by "the fonts are not replaced in the document"?

Comment: @jarnosz it means that the compiled document appears typeset with the LaTeX default font (computer modern) instead of the TTF font (Open Sans)

Comment: what does `kpsewhich OpenSans-Regular-osf-t1.ttf` report?

Comment: @jarnosz it reports nothing. Nothing appears in the screen.

Comment: your system is not finding the font; try `mktexlsr` on the command prompt to update the kpathsea databases, and `kpsewhich` again to see...